# Harmonic oscillator differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics, classical-mechanics

Consider a harmonic oscillator subject to a frictional force proportional to velocity: $$\ddot{x}+2\gamma\dot{x}+\omega^2x=0.$$
Here $\dot{x}$ and $\ddot{x}$ are $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}.$ Assume $\omega>\gamma.$ Interpreting this equation as a system of equations for two functions $x\left ( t\right ) $ and $\nu\left ( t\right ) = \dot{x} \left ( t\right ) $, solve this system of equations and show that the solutions are:

$$\begin{gathered}
x\left(t\right)=\mathrm{e}^{-\gamma t}\left[x_0\cos\left(\Omega t\right)+x_0\frac\gamma\Omega\sin\left(\Omega t\right)+\nu_0\frac1\Omega\sin\left(\Omega t\right)\right]; \\
\nu\left(t\right)=\mathrm{e}^{-\gamma t}\left[-x_{0}\frac{\omega^{2}}\Omega\sin\left(\Omega t\right)+\nu_{0}\cos\left(\Omega t\right)-\nu_{0}\frac\gamma\Omega\sin\left(\Omega t\right)\right]. 
\end{gathered}$$
Here, $x_0= x\left ( 0\right ) $ and $\nu_0= \nu\left ( 0\right ) $ are initial conditions. What is the frequency $\Omega$ of these oscillations?

**My attempt:**

Let's introduce a new variable $v(t) = \dot{x}(t)$ so that we have $$\begin{cases}\dot{x}&=v\\\dot{v}&=-2\gamma v-\omega^2x&\end{cases}$$
Now, we have a system of first-order ordinary differential equations. We can rewrite this in matrix form as:
$$\frac d{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x\\v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\times x+1\times v\\-\omega^2\times x+(-2\gamma)\times v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-\omega^2&-2\gamma\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\v\end{bmatrix}$$
The solution to this system can be found by diagonalizing the coefficient matrix. Let's denote the coefficient matrix by $A$:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-\omega^2&-2\gamma\end{bmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues $\lambda$ and eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}$ of $A$ satisfy the equation: $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, so we have
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}-\lambda&1\\-\omega^2&-2\gamma-\lambda\end{pmatrix}=0 \implies\lambda=-\gamma\pm\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2}$$
Since $\omega > \gamma$, the term under the square root is negative, resulting in complex conjugate eigenvalues. Let's denote $\Omega = \sqrt{\omega^2 - \gamma^2}$, so the eigenvalues become: $$\lambda=-\gamma\pm i\Omega.$$

Now, we can write down the general solution using these eigenvalues. The general solution has the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\v(t)\end{bmatrix}=c_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\-\gamma+i\Omega\end{bmatrix}e^{(-\gamma+i\Omega)t}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\-\gamma-i\Omega\end{bmatrix}e^{(-\gamma-i\Omega)t}$$ $$\begin{aligned}
&x\left(t\right) =c_1e^{(-\gamma+i\Omega)t}+c_2e^{(-\gamma-i\Omega)t}  \\
&v(t) =(-\gamma+i\Omega)c_1e^{(-\gamma+i\Omega)t}+(-\gamma-i\Omega)c_2e^{(-\gamma-i\Omega)t} 
\end{aligned}$$ Then, finding the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ in terms of $x_0$ and $v_0$ I get
$$\frac{x_0 i \Omega+v_0+\gamma x_0}{2i \Omega}=c_1$$ and $$-\frac{v_0+\gamma x_0-i \Omega x_0}{2i \Omega}=c_2,$$ if I haven't made any errors.

Thus plugging in and applying Euler's formula,
$$\begin{gathered}
x(t)=\left(\frac{x_0i\Omega+v_0+\gamma x_0}{2i\Omega}\right)e^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\Omega t)+i\sin(\Omega t)) \\
+\left(-\frac{v_0+\gamma x_0-i\Omega x_0}{2i\Omega}\right)e^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\Omega t)-i\sin(\Omega t)) 
\end{gathered}$$ and $$\begin{gathered}
\begin{aligned}v(t)=(-\gamma+i\Omega)\left(\frac{x_0i\Omega+v_0+\gamma x_0}{2i\Omega}\right)e^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\Omega t)+i\sin(\Omega t))\end{aligned} \\
+(-\gamma-i\Omega)\left(-\frac{v_0+\gamma x_0-i\Omega x_0}{2i\Omega}\right)e^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\Omega t)-i\sin(\Omega t)) 
\end{gathered}$$
But I am having trouble simplifying it to get to the solutions as written.

Btw, am I correct in assuming $\Omega$ as frequency in this physical context? Furthermore, how do we calculate the frequency $Ω$ of these oscillations?

Comment: You already found  the angular frequency as $\Omega=\sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega^2}$ So what is your question? you just have to combine imaginary part and real part to get sin and cos .

Comment: Is the last equation correct so far? I don't see how I can turn it into the final form as showed. I am also having doubts about my interpretation of $\Omega$ as well, since I don't know whether my assumption is correct in this case

Comment: Maybe a look at [Aperiodischer Grenzfall](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodischer_Grenzfall) could help -- sorry, there was no link to the English version.

Comment: You haven't yet used the initial conditions, so how can you expect to have turned it into their final form? Do that first. I would also suggest doing this _before_ using Euler's formula, to make the algebra a bit easier.

Comment: @Semiclassical am not sure how it simplifies, I tried substituting right before using Euler's formula and got $x(0)=x_0=c_1+c_2$ and $v(0)=v_0=(-\gamma + i \Omega)c_1+(-\gamma - i \Omega)c_2$. I don't see how it helps me?

Comment: Now solve for $c_1,c_2$ in terms of $x_0,v_0$ and plug these back in.

Comment: @Semiclassical I got $\frac{x_0 i \Omega+v_0+\gamma x_0}{2i \Omega}=c_1$ and $-\frac{v_0+\gamma x_0-i \Omega x_0}{2i \Omega}=c_2$, if I haven't made any errors.

Comment: Plugging and using Euler's I got $\begin{gathered}
x(t)=\left(\frac{x_0i\Omega+v_0+\gamma x_0}{2i\Omega}\right)e^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\Omega t)+i\sin(\Omega t)) \\
+\left(-\frac{v_0+\gamma x_0-i\Omega x_0}{2i\Omega}\right)e^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\Omega t)-i\sin(\Omega t)) 
\end{gathered}$ and $\begin{gathered}
\begin{aligned}v(t)=(-\gamma+i\Omega)\left(\frac{x_0i\Omega+v_0+\gamma x_0}{2i\Omega}\right)e^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\Omega t)+i\sin(\Omega t))\end{aligned} \\
+(-\gamma-i\Omega)\left(-\frac{v_0+\gamma x_0-i\Omega x_0}{2i\Omega}\right)e^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\Omega t)-i\sin(\Omega t)) 
\end{gathered}$

Comment: Is there any way to simplify further because I don't see it yet?

Comment: I would recommend distributing out the exponential decay and then determining the real and imaginary components of each term. Remember that $\frac{1}{i}=\frac{i}{i^2}=-i$.

Comment: @DarkLordOfPhysics Thanks for suggestion, can you tell what is exponential decay and how to use it in this context, I am not really familiar with it besides the formula $\frac{dN}{dt}=-\lambda N.$

Comment: $N(t)=e^{-\gamma t}$ satisfies this with $\lambda = \gamma$ in this case. This is the general solution up to a multiplicative constant for your formula and indeed what I mean by exponential decay. Physically, this factor represents how the damping will make the system come to rest at the origin as $t \to \infty$. It is often easier to distribute $N(t)$ out to remind yourself of this behavior and make the algebraic manipulation simpler. It is also this way in the final form of $x(t),v(t)$ you would like to obtain.